# How to make form label and content inline?

Tags: css, forms, webforms, label, inline

I need to align label and content in a form but no code I tried worked.

Expected

[image]

currently look like

[image]

The css code I created is this:

```
.crm-webform, .crm-webform-label,  .crm-webform-fieldset, .crm-webform-input-label, .crm-webform-group, .crm-webform-input, .crm-webform-label-content  {font-family: Open sans, 'Open sans', Lato, sans-serif;   font-size:14px;   color:black; margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px; } 

.crm-webform-input {height: 32px; }  .crm-webform-icon  {height: 22px; line-height: 30px;}  #LEAD_UF_CRM_5BEF2B8E126AA  { padding:  1px 3px 1px 3px;  height:60px; resize: both;
  overflow: auto;} label[for=LEAD_UF_CRM_1550937652],  label[for=LEAD_UF_CRM_1550937755] {height:0px; color:transparent; opacity:0; margin: 0px 6px 0px 6px;}

.flexible-middle-width, .crm-webform-header-container {background-color:transparent; background-opacity:0.4;}

/*#bx_form_iframe_6 ,  .crm-webform-block  .bx_form_iframe_12       */   

.*, *  {background-color:transparent; background-opacity:0.4; font-family:Open-sans, Open sans, 'Open sans', Lato, sans-serif; color:black;   }

h1, .crm-webform-header {color:black; font-family:Open-sans, 'Open sans', Lato, sans-serif;  font-weight: bold; size:26px;  letter-spacing: 1px; margin: 6px 0px 0px 0px;}

.crm-webform-input {font-weight:600; }  .crm-webform-checkbox-container, .crm-webform-checkbox-radio,  .crm-webform-checkbox-name {display:inline; font-family:Open-sans,'Open sans', Lato, sans-serif;     font-size:14px;    color:black;  padding: 0px 4px 0px 9px;}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide the HTML as well?

Comment: I cannot, I am limited by 30000 characters. It is done in Bitrix24.

Comment: view-source:https://b24-31htk0.bitrix24.eu/pub/form.php?view=frame&form_id=12&widget_user_lang=en&sec=t4s50k&r=1551359113314#%7B%22domain%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fulovmi.cz%22%2C%22from%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fulovmi.cz%2Fpoptavka%2F%22%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%7D%7D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set these attributes to this class `.crm-webform-field-string` (or create another class as well) it will work:

```
.crm-webform-field-string {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

The rest is only to set a `margin-right` to the label container.

For example:

```
margin-right: 30px;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying "flex", but without the align part.

Now however the right gap has become wider. Can this be solved?   https://imgur.com/a/vBZj3vP

Also, I want to stretch some of the fields like this: https://imgur.com/a/G8CCjon and inline three fields together: https://imgur.com/a/xQOkN3P

Comment: Well first you have to set the ´label´ width to 100%, that erases the gap, and for the stretch fields, you can use a calc(100% - 'label-width') on the parent's CSS. Remember to vote!

Comment: This makes the title stretch (imgur.com/a/cbOmikI). How do I use calc?

CSS: ".crm-webform-label,  .crm-webform-fieldset, .crm-webform-input-label, .crm-webform-group, .crm-webform-input, .crm-webform-label-content  {font-family: Open sans, 'Open sans', Lato, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:black; margin: 0px 12px 4px 0px; width: 100%;}   
.crm-webform-field-string, .crm-webform-field-integer, .crm-webform-field-date, .crm-webform-field-email  { display: flex;  align-items:center;  width: 100%;}  .crm-webform-field-integer  {width:260px; padding: 0px 40px 0px -40px; width: 100%;}"

Comment: Ok the thing is that you have common classes (which will make you change all the inputs), so you have two choices: 1) to set a new class for this kind of inputs, or 2) set it by id, like div#field_LEAD_UF_CRM_5BEF13BE4AF41_CONT {
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
}

Comment: That just does this: https://imgur.com/a/7heNMmJ Any other way to keep the title on one row? (Btw I cannot edit any HTML, just CSS)

Comment: This should do it (you can play with the px amount): .crm-webform-field-date .crm-webform-group {
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
}

Comment: That just makes a border underneath but does not change the title nor group the three fields to one row: https://imgur.com/4pf0ldx